# code before app.run() can not be run in gunicorn+flask

Tags: flask, gunicorn

```
#main.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    print("before app run")
    app.run()  # , threaded=True host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5000
```

Run gunicorn as follow:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --preload main:app
```

the result will not print “before app unn”. How can i run the print code? if i don't want to place print outside of `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gunicorn is not running the file, but `import`ing it. That means that `__name__ != "__main__"` and your code never gets run.

Gunicorn then manually calls `app.run()` itself, after importing your file.

The solution is to make sure that your code is run at import time:

```
> cat main.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

print "before main stanza"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "in main stanza"
    app.run()
```

And then running the app:

```
> gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --preload main:app
before main stanza
[2017-06-07 08:33:15 +0100] [8865] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-06-07 08:33:15 +0100] [8865] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (8865)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually that will print `before app run` when you run this application with `python main.py`

It's not possible with Gunicorn though you can try `before_first_request` that will do the trick

```
@app.before_first_request
def execute_this():
    print("before app run")
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way to do this is with the decorator as mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44406033/7584553) but `@app.before_first_request` is deprecated since Flask 2.2 and will be removed in 2.3 [as mentioned here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request)

Use this instead:

```
with app.app_context():
  print("before app run")
```

If you run the app with `debug=True`, then the code inside tends to run twice. Just turn it off to prevent that