# Gunicorn does not execute statements within main

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    pass
    #Some statements to predict something


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello World")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

When I run as 
`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0 app:app` I do not see the print statement. However when I run as `python app.py`, the "Hello World" gets printed. The app runs but it does not execute the print statement. Any idea what causes the Gunicorn to ignore what is within main()?

Comment: This is exactly what the `if` statement is for.

Comment: Why would you expect your test driver to run when a real driver is running?

Comment: @KlausD.: I am starting to see what you mean. Basically we are calling the app to run directly from the `gunicorn` statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you run as `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0 app:app`, gunicorn will only import the app from your `app.py` file. It will skip statements from the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block and hence you're not seeing the output from the print statement.

But when you run as `python app.py`, `if __name__ == '__main__'` block will be the entry point and hence print statement gets executed.

Also note that, the `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)` line in `if __name__ == '__main__'` will start the development server and not the gunicorn server.

Attaching the link here for the similar question:
[code before app.run() can not be run in gunicorn+flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405909/code-before-app-run-can-not-be-run-in-gunicornflask)